# Remove document from Stack

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Stream Builder which populates a Stack of cards:

```
_showCards() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: cardReference.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return circularProgress();
          }
          return Stack(children: fillCards(snapshot));
        });
  }
```

```
fillCards(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents
        .map((doc) => buildCards(
              image: doc["mediaUrl"],
              title: doc["title"],
              type: doc["description"],
            ))
        .toList();
  }
```

I want to remove the top snapshot on the Stack with a skip button. How could I manage the snapshots to access a certain index?

**Edit:**

I need to remove the card from the Stack view, not actually delete it from the database. I'm thinking I should use a List and use .removeAt(index), but not sure how to add snapshots from Firestore to a list. I currently have a map of documents as you can see in fillCards().

```
Widget buildCards({image, title, type}) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      // UI showing Image Url, title and description in a Card.
      // then I have an icon, to skip the card on top and show the one behind
         IconButton(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.forward,
          color: Colors.greenAccent, size: 21),
          onPressed: () => //SKIP CARD
```

Comment: What happen if you skipped the first element and then a new list arrives? The first element of that new list should be removed?

Comment: It doesn't have to be removed, skipping is okay. But is it possible to do that with my map of docs in fillCards?

Comment: I know, I mean removing from the stack. The thing is what will happen if a new list arrives after you already skipped the first element, should the new list have its first element skipped too?

Comment: Ideally it would go to the last element, cause if the user completes the task through all of them, skipped cards could show up again.

Comment: Could you post what is the functionality you are trying to achieve? I mean, what are the elements and how the card is skipped by the user. Because I could tell you how to skip the first element, but I think skipping the first element may not be the right approach if after that new elements arrives.

Comment: Just updated, thanks! I think skipping is a good solution for now. But otherwise I'll read more into fetching data into Lists with flutter, and work with remove at that index.

Comment: According to your edit, every item will have a skip button, so you don't want to just skip the first one on the list, but any item whose skip button is pressed?

Comment: Exactly. Then the next card behind the stack comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to skip any item of the list received when tapping the skip button of the item.

Here are some ways to do this:

- If the list is particular from a user, you could mark the item on the
  database as "skipped" and when you show the list, just show the items
  that aren't "skipped".
- If the list could be shared with different users, you could create another list for each user, with "skipped" ids. Then show the items whose ids aren't in that user "skipped" list.
- If you want to handle this on client side, without altering the database, you could create a list of "skipped" ids and when you show the list, just show the items that aren't on that "skipped" list.

Here is an idea for the last option:

```
final _skippedIds = List();

// The filtered list
snapshot.data.documents.where((doc) => !_skippedIds.contains(doc["id"])).map(...

// The onTap of each skip button:
onTap: () => setState(() => _skippedIds.add(doc["id"])),
```

Also, you could save on `SharedPreferences` the list of skipped ids.

Answer (score 0):

Were I you in that situation, I make a viewModel and copy data of documents to the viewModel. Then I only modify the viewModel to manage views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant to ask how to remove the card from the Stack view, not actually delete it from the database. I'm thinking I should use a list and use removeAt(index), but not sure how to add snapshots from firestore to a list.

Comment: I understand you are saying! I fixed my answer.